# iOS7 , In CollectionView , When will this method be called? layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiview

I'm a new iOS developer.

Recently I'm learning UICollectionView and I'm trying to subclass the UICollectionViewLayout.

I have to implement the method

> -(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect

## Question

#### I have no idea where did this rect come from? and in which scenario will this rect be passed to me ?

PS. I think this method might be more easy to understand

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
```

Because the indexPath is limited and finite and configure the cell in the particular indexPath is reasonable.

But the rect might be infinite and I have no idea where this rect came from.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a layout subclass you must override both methods.

The `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` tells the collection-view what are the layout attributes for a cell at a specific index-path. You must only use it for cells.

The `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` gets called by the system with a rectangle which contains all "visual elements" to be displayed in it - cells, supplementary or decoration views. Think of it as the part of the collection-view that's about to be displayed. It tells the collection-view which attributes are contained in the rectangle, so it can create the corresponding views.

Basically, you can do all your layout attribute calculations (frame, transforms, etc.) inside these functions, or you can prepare all attributes in advance (you can do that in the `prepareLayout` method) and just return the correct cached layout attributes.

Comment: Thx so much!  but what exactly does this rect mean? And if I only touch the screen moving only 1px ,  will the rect change? Finally  what the relation between collectionViewContentSize , ScreenSize and this Rect ? (Drawing a picture will be better , Thank you!)

Comment: two question: 1、 is the rect always visible ? if not so , why?   2、 if I  touch the screen and I only  move 1px , will the rect change ?

Comment: @tiper basically it's the rect for all visible elements, but you should not assume anything about the systems' internal logic for calling this method, you just need to return the corresponding attributes for the requested rect. I think you should just build a test project and play with it, put some break points and see for yourself when theses methods get called.